# Jquery slidedown hidden element onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a hmtl structure like this that repeats an indefinite amount of times

```
 <div class='rr'>
  <div class='rrclk'>
   Click Me
  </div>
  <div class='rrshow'>
    I am now shown
   </div>
```

Is there any way to only show the rrshow in the parent of the rrclk that was clicked? So that if you clicked one rrclk only the rrshow that was in the same rr would be shown, if that makes any sense.

Thanks

EDIT:

Thanks, is there any way i could do the same thing with AJAX, like this:

```
$('.rrclk').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'getdata.php',
        data: {
            uid: this.id
        },
        success: function (data) {
   $(this).parent().find(".rrshow").html(data);
   $(this).parent().find(".rrshow").fadeToggle("fast");
        }
    });
```

Comment: What have you tried? Surely you did not come here just to make someone write the code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this is what you want

```
$(".rrclk").click(function(){
   //hide all rrshow
   $(".rrshow").hide();

   //show only required rrshow
   $(this).parent().find(".rrshow").show();
});
```

here is a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/qEJza/1/)**

Comment: Thanks, is there any way i could do the same this and get the .rrshow via ajax? I added the code in the question

Comment: It isn't working. Mind you, this is all run from within another Ajax call. Is it possible to run call an ajax function from within an ajax function?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.rrclk').click(function() {
    $(this).next().show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.rr .rrclk').click(function(){
   $(this).siblings('.rrshow').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By using jQuery show() and hide() methods you can fix this,
first set an id to the div

```
$("# place rrshow id here").show();
$("# place rrshow id here").hide();


$("#place rrclk id here").click(function(){
//$("# place rrshow id here").show(); or $("# place rrshow id here").hide(); whatever you want
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.rrclk').click(function(){
$(this).siblings('.rrshow').show();
});
```

you could use this jquery, if I understand you correctly,

Here is a JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/fb4gr/

​